# Scale the position of child elements, but not their size?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am implementing behavior in my application that will resize the main content area depending on the screen size. (The content area is made up of icons and other elements that the user can place/draw)

Currently, the margin property is used to position elements using a converter that converts a `Point` to `Thickness`.

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kg4o.png]

I need to "scale" the child elements position to the size of the container. The *position* of the elements is all that needs to be scaled, **not** the size.

How can I apply a transform (`RenderTransform` or `LayoutTransform`) to all *child* elements of a grid, so that the icon positions will scale to the correct position depending on the grid size?

It should also be noted that these icons may be removed/added while the application is running.

Comment: Wouldn't a `ViewBox` help here?

Comment: Are you trying to simply scale the size of all elements, or should only the size of the container change?

Comment: The size of the container will change and the _position_ of the elements will scale to them.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such thing you are looking for in XAML. You could use a Canvas and set relative to the closest side, but this would not scale the distances, it would only move the elements accordingly. What I would do is listen to the Window.SizeChanged event and scale the distances programmatically.

Comment: To be clear, the window is not dynamically resized, the size is chosen automatically through SizeToContent. (Which will fill as much as the screen as possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already done this before, and I would suggest you to do this:

1. In your element class (say, `Circle`), you have some sort of coordinate representing their position, *proportionally* to the size of the container. So, `0.5` would represent the middle, `0.33` would represent one third to the left, etc.
2. Create an [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that calculates the pixel coordinate based on the relative coordinate and the container size along a given dimension;
3. Declare your object in XAML with its margins (in case of a Grid container) or Canvas.Top/Left (in case of a Canvas container) in the following way:

Xaml:

```
<Circle>
    <Circle.Margin>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThatConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="container" Path="ActualWidth"/>
            <Binding Path="CircleCoordinateX"/>
            <!-- The same for height and Y coordinate -->
        </MultiBinding>
    </Circle.Margin>
</Circle>
```

Instead of this more simplistic approach, ideally you should make your container to be an `ItemsControl`, create an `ItemsTemplate` for datatype `Circle`, and bind the container `ItemsSource` to some ObservableCollection on some viewmodel, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt to implement this now.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll be at work, and I can copy-paste some working code sample if you are still interested.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, I may have found a different solution (Using my existing `PointToThickness` converter for converting a point to margin, similar to your idea) If I can't get it done by the end of today I'll try your method.

Comment: After becoming frustrated with my own similar idea, I realized a multivalue converter is what I needed. Congrats on the 6k btw :)

Comment: Thanks, @Cyral! :D Just to elaborate further on the "multivalueconverter" thing: every positioning of an object relative to a 2D container intrinsically depends on 2*2=4 parameters: two world coordinates on the object, and two device coordinates on the container. You could achieve this either with one multiconverter that returns one 2D position from 4 scalar coordinates, or two multiconverters that return 1 coordinate each from 2 parameters each. There is no way that I know (and I believe there isn't at all) to get this with simple data-binding.